# PHP localization files for Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I can't find localization files for Laravel 9 with php format **(not json)** to add new languages to my app.

This (most popular i guess) one consists of json files only: https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang

Comment: Which kind of file are you looking for? If this should be something provided by Laravel itself, you should better ask this in their issue tracker

Comment: @NicoHaase i need to find repository where all the translations exists. I need to set up swedish translation for now

Comment: What kind of repository are you searching? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase i need to add another language. So i need to find translation files for this language

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question. Do you need to add a language to Laravel's core? To your own application? To any other existing application?

Answer (score 2):

> Laravel provides two ways to manage translation strings. First, language strings may be stored in files within the **`lang`** directory. Within this directory, there may be subdirectories for each language supported by the application. This is the approach Laravel uses to manage translation strings for built-in Laravel features such as validation error messages:

You could insert these PHP files or choose the 2nd method :

```
/lang
    /en
        messages.php
    /es
        messages.php
```

**2nd Method :**

> Or, translation strings may be defined within JSON files that are placed within the lang directory. When taking this approach, each language supported by your application would have a corresponding JSON file within this directory. This approach is recommended for applications that have a large number of translatable strings:

```
/lang
en.json
es.json
```

[Laravel 9 Localization](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization)

[Sample lang folder and files in github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/9.x/lang)

Comment: sorry i didn't say i need to add new language files. It's swedish for now.

Comment: @AnatolySokolov Go to config/app.php and change 'locale' to 'en'

Comment: @royal-mgh how it should help to add Swedish language?

Comment: @AnatolySokolov I provide a link in my answer click on it ( Sample lang folder and files in GitHub ), same as example create new folder in lang directory and rename it to sv, then copy 4php files from the en directory into sv directory and then edit the translation in Swedish language

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang package with Laravel languages moved to json only translation files but i found latest release with php files: https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang/releases/tag/10.9.5

Comment: Why do you care about an outdated version of that project?